# My self-hosted blog won't route properly past the first lookup

Tags: networking, dns, routing

I have moved from hosted WordPress to hosting my own on my QNAP NAS. Now, I've gotten it to work insofar that I can lookup the blog from the Internet (I've set up an A record at my domain service). The problem is that as soon as I click on any links inside my blog, it will route me to the local IP of my NAS instead of to my domain name.

What have I missed in my setup?

I have only set up an A record for the specific subdomain of my blog, the main domain is just parked.

Comment: What are your wordpress settings for WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL) under Settings/General?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are your wordpress settings for WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL) under Settings/General? This probably is set to the IP instead of the DNS name.